# How do I add a newline character to a string in Python?

Tags: python, file

I am adding names and scores into a file and was trying to figure out how to start a newline after writing data to the file. This is my code so far, but when I go on in the file, all of the variables are on the same line:

```
print "That's the game folks! You finished with a final score of...", points, 'points! Good game, you made the high score list! What is your name?'
name = raw_input()
w = open('Highscores', 'a')
w.write(name)
w.write(str(points))
w.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` for new lines on unix or `\r\n` for windows.  Just add to the end of the string.

```
w.write(str(points) + '\n')
```

or

```
print "That's the game folks! You finished with a final score of...", points, 'points! Good game, you made the high score list! What is your name?\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following,

```
print(name, points, sep=":", file="Highscores") # Mike:23
```

You don't even have to do `str(points)`. Works for any data type. And adds a newline by default. It is very **efficient** compared to custom acrobatics using `.write()`.(*Beazly*)

Answer (score 0):

This becomes prettier in Py3:

```
print("That's the game folks! You scored %i points! Your name?" % points)
with open('Highscores', 'a') as w:
    print('%s %i' % (input(), points), file=w)
```

If you only want a single entry per user (i.e. the highest score of a particular user and no duplicates), you could use a dictionary and do something like this:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> def save_score(name, score):
...     try:
...         d = literal_eval(open('score').read())
...     except:
...         d = {}
...     if name not in d or d[name] < score:
...         d[name] = score
...         open('score', 'w').write(str(d))
...
>>> save_score('Jack', 5)
>>> save_score('Jill', 10)
>>> open('score').read()
"{'Jill': 10, 'Jack': 5}"
```